# web.py printing the html code on Apache server

Tags: python, apache, web.py

I have web.py configured for my Apache server by installing flups. However when I go to my application, the html code is printed instead of the html page. (See below).

```
Content-Type: text/html

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Login Details</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>.......</BODY></HTML>
```

I created another file Test.py in the same directory with the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html><head></head><body>Present</body></html>"
```

This prints out the page fine. Both the files have the same executable permissions.(chmod 755).

Any ideas why this is happening?

**Update:** Just found out. If I change the return statement to a print inside the GET method for my app, it prints out the form fine, but also prints out the cookie, session id, etc.. at the end. What do I need to configure to make the return work as expected?

Adding a sample code which would cause the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import web
urls = ("/CodeAnalyzer", "CodeAnalyzer")
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class CodeAnalyzer:
    def GET(self):
        init="Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
        form="<html><head></head><body>Hello World</body><html>"
        return init+form

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: What is "my application"? We need code for it.

Comment: The code is not an issue. It works fine if I use the server in built with web.py. The issue comes when I'm running it on my Apache server. I'll update a sample code though.

Comment: can you please take care with your code formatting? Look at the preview before submitting!  See what I've done (and redone because you broke it by editing in the wrong way, destroying my changes).

Comment: sorry about that... any tips for the issue tho???

Comment: Why are you adding "Content-Type: text/html" to the output ??

Comment: @Pankaj: If I want to write html in a python file, I start with that. I'm not sure about the web.py way (I think it should be same). Even without that line, the issue still exists.

Comment: I also don't know why you're adding the `Content-Type: text/html` line. Are you going for `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`?

Comment: @Wildduck: I tried without the line. The issue still exists. And for printing html in cgi, we print out the line first so that we print out the html page and not the code. Like a header. It turns out that the header needs to be passed but in a seperate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in the line
`init="Content-Type: text/html\n\n"`
That was the incorrect way to pass the header in web.py. The issue was resolved after replacing it with 
`web.header('Content-Type','text/html; charset=utf-8', unique=True)`

Comment: @Helgi: My reputation does not allow me to do so... Atleast until 2 days... :P